# Certificte Pinning with PHP not working

Tags: php, ssl, curl, tls1.2, public-key-pinning

I'm trying to connect to a Web Service, which requires SSL Certificate pinning.
Previous implementation has been done with Java and now I have to convert it to PHP.

I converted the JKS to a pem file and using it like below.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "F:\www\key.pem"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
/// END     - CERTIFICATION ///

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_user_registration);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);


if ($result == false) {
    echo "Satrt:";
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo $result;
    echo ":End";
}
else{
    echo "No Error";
}
```

But I'm getting below error.

```
error:14082174:SSL routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:dh key too small
```

Have anyone faced this issue. Am I doing something wrong or is the Web Service is having some issue.

Comment: I don't agree on comment "Pinning is something the server does". Certificate pinning is done by the client, as for my knowledge certificate chain is shared with the trusted client in-advance and store in jks or pem etc... file and use that to validate the remote host when you connect to host. but you can do that 2 way on more hostile environments.

Comment: Also, I'm not going to go into production with  "cURL options to not verify". Also, I found a good article on this issue and resolved the issue. Will add the solution as an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was not with my script but the server itself. Certificate used by this particular service is outdated. But my PHP scripts run on a newer version of RedHat which has the latest CURL version.

This curl version does not support smaller Diffie-Hellman keys. Precisely, it does not support keys smaller than 1023. So I modified my server to accept keys as small as 768 by modifying nss configurations.

My service provider is going to update their certificate.

Found a very good article on this issue - [CURL issue with NSS 3.28.4-3.0.1 - curl: (35) SSL connect error - ciphers rsa_rc4_128 only working](http://myblogmchopker.blogspot.com/2017/07/curl-issue-with-nss-3284-301-curl-35.html)  by Mahesh Chopker